# Timeout en ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

Tengo problemas con una aplicación `ASP .NET MVC`. La aplicación hace un timeout a los 20 minutos aproximadamente y no se realiza nada en ella.

Tengo estas líneas en el `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Cuenta/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

He desactivado la sesión de esta forma, pensando que sería eso, pero sigo con los mismos problemas.

```
<sessionState mode="Off" timeout="2880" />
```

¿Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés.

Comment: La costumbre, traducida.

Comment: suele pasar!  retirado el voto.

Comment: lograste hacerlo funcionar? te han sido de utilidad las respuestas?

Comment: Hola @fredyfx , disculpa he marcado como respuesta bien la del último chico, mi código funciona bien, pero también depende de la configuración de IIS, se supone que, debería automáticamente ponerse la configuración que subes en el web.config pero di con un servidor un poco toca pelotas, pero finalmente lo hice ir!

Comment: Me parece perfecto :D sigue con todo el power 2.0 al desarrollo! Saludos

Comment: Para toda la gente que le da problemas también el tema de la sesión, comentaros que, accediendo aquí ---> IIS >> WIN-VN... >> ASP >> Servicios >> Propiedades de la sesión >> Tiempo de espera.

Se configura también el tiempo de la sesión, si es inferior al de tu web.config, hará caso a este. Ir con ojo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para definir el timeout (en minutos) en MVC se hace así en el web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="90"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

El valor por defecto es 20 (por eso ahora mismo a los 20 minutos se sale)

Comment: Lo tengo en OFF aparte en 2880 minutos (2 días)

Answer (score 2):

Para finalizar bien la sesión necesitas dos cosas. Primero que la sesion finalice en el servidor y 2º que la vista que está activa desaparezca y se muestre la vista de Login.cshtml.

1º - Para que la sesion finalice en el servidor necesitas modifica el Web.config y añadir...:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="90"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

2º - Necesitas tambien forzar al cierre de la sesion cuando el sistema lleve unos minutos de inactividad. Para eso puedes utilizar este script. La forma de llamarlo puede ser desde la pagina _Layout.cshtml que es la Vista de diseño, "masterpage",...Lo bueno es que el script afectará a todas las paginas que utilicen la misma pagina maestra. Entonces debes llamar al script haciendo ...

```
<body onload="VigilaActividad()">
```

- Recuerda que en MVC para que una vista utilice una pagina maestra debesponer en la parte superior...

  @{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

Y para finalizar colocas el codigo javascript **al final de la vista _Layout.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Vigila la actividad del sistema.
// --------------------------------
function VigilaActividad() {

    // Contador de tiempo en el que el usuario está inactivo.
    // ------------------------------------------------------
    var segundosDesdeUltimaActividad = 0;

    // Recuperamos del Controlador el valor timeOut definido en sessionState del Web.config
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var timeOut = '@Convert.ToInt32(((System.Web.Configuration.SessionStateSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState")).Timeout.TotalMinutes)';

    var maximaInactividad = timeOut * 60; 

    // A intervalos de 1 segundo (1000) revisa el estado del contador.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    setInterval(function () {
        segundoDesdeUltimaActividad++;

        if (segundosDesdeUltimaActividad > maximaInactividad) {
            location.href = '../Account/login';
        }
    }, 1000);

    // Esta funcion inicializa el contador de inactividad, sucede cuando se detecta que el usuario está trabajando...
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function reseteaActividad() {
        segundosDesdeUltimaActividad = 0;
    }

    // Vector con los eventos que vigila.
    // ----------------------------------
    var EventosActividad = [
        'keydown', 'keypress', 'scroll', 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'touchstart', 'resize'
    ];

    // Creamos "Escuchadores" de eventos al documento...
    // -------------------------------------------------
    EventosActividad.forEach(function (eventName) {
        document.addEventListener(eventName, reseteaActividad, true);
    });
}
```

En resumen, cuando el usuario deje de trabajar se inicariá un conteo de ineactividad del sistema y esté conteo se inicializará cuando se detecte nuevamente activiad por 
parte del usuario. Si el conteo de inactividad alcanza el valor definido en el timeOut
entonces saldrá del sistema y nos mostrará nuevamente la pantalla de login.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si lo que quieres es que no haga timeout nunca o si quieres extenderlo más en el tiempo. Creo que el tiempo máximo de timout de sessión es 1 año, pero personalmente prefiero no alargar innecesariamente el tiempo de timeout desde el webconfig. Piensa que una sesión larga de 1 año por ejemplo mantendrá toda la info en el lado del servidor. Si tienes mucho usuarios es inviable.

Si lo que quieres es que nunca expire la sesión puedes hacer un hack en javascript para que se autologuee cada X tiempo.

Aquí la solución https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive

En este ejemplo se realiza un latido (heartbeat) cada 5 minutos (configurable) Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Buenas Hector,
Gracias por tu rápida respuesta, te explico:
No quiero que caduque la sesión enseguida, de hecho si tenía activada la sesión el hecho de desactivarla ha sido para ir haciendo pruebas. Mi idea es que la sesión sea de aproximadamente 90 minutos y luego por JS tal y como tengo un script (con un onclick en cualquier sitio dentro de la etiqueta html). Este comprueba la fecha que se guarda en cookie cada vez que se realiza algo y entonces dependiendo lo redirige a Login o no. Pero tengo problemas con ello y no encuentro ningún manual ni nada que me diga como hacerlo para que vaya OK

Comment: Tendría que ver el proyecto pero por lo que me cuentas creo que no necesitas el onClick dentro del html para comprobar si no tiene sesión. Para establecer bien el tiempo de sesión, suelo basarme en esto https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.timeout.aspx

Comment: y poniendo el SlidingExpiration a False   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration.aspx

Comment: Le hecho un vistazo a tu pregunta y te digo Hector.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Buenas Hector, he puesto esto:

   <forms loginUrl="~/Cuenta/Login" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="false" />


Sigue tirandome fuera, al cabo de un rato (no mas de 30 minutos) me da un 302 y se me intenta ir al login, sin quitar layout ni nada...

Answer (score 0):

> Para finalizar bien la sesión necesitas dos cosas. Primero que la sesion finalice en el servidor y 2º que la vista que está activa desaparezca y se muestre la vista de Login.cshtml.

Adolfo Gómez tu respuesta me fue útil en cierta forma pero solo en el index ingreso a otra pagina de la aplicación y ya no realiza la validación me puedes dar ayudar con alguna idea de lo que se deba este error ?